# Persistent datatable filtering over several pages while conversation scoped bean does't retain

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Persistent datatable filtering over several pages while conversation scoped bean doesn't retain (primefaces 5.1 is used) after submit (on another page)  clicked and gone back to the starting screen.

I know that the possible solution should be implemneted by extending the DataTable and FilterFeature classes. Can somebody link here any solution? I can imagine this is already solved somewhere.